# how to php encrypt passwords to 128 character?

Tags: php, encryption, md5

I want to encrypt php passwords to 128 characters, how is that possible?

I know that I cant use md5 but cant find something specific wish sha or hash.

Comment: Do you mean "encrypt" or do you mean "hash"?

Comment: Why? Is there a specific reason you need 128 characters?

Comment: You can *hash* the password and print the hash in hex or in Base64 -- but that's not "encrypting".

Comment: Whereever you got that idea from, you probably misread "bits" for "characters".

Comment: To clarify, 'encryption' is reversible.  Hashing is not, but you can compare a string to the hash to see if they are equal.  So if you need to decrypt the password to plain text, you want encryption.  Else, hashing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth He must mean hash, as it is impossible to encrypt a password of more than 128 characters to 128 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sha512` is 128 characters. The `whirlpool`, `salsa10`, and `salsa20` algorithms are also 128-character hashes that ship with PHP.

Comment: @EugenRieck: You can represent each bit by a random choice from a predefined bipartite alphabet, though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ofcourse it is not ... can I -1 myself? It is 512 Bits.

Comment: @KerrekSB by chosing a tasty representation, you can create a nearly random bit-count for the REPRESENTATION, which doesn't mean it contains more than **512** bit (yes, I am sorry) of information