# In Yii framework want to know the password type???

Tags: yii

I Create a API of reset password. and the project use yii framework so i dont get the type of password encoding Plz help me to find the type of password the password show in 128 digit

Password:

1234567  in database shown :

a711df782e24d90ff59725fa2b4ba16178676506cd411ebbd8ff2360420f8f5f728b7ab09c60358c084d634a7d3363c3f733e6746154f959767f08d2f2725afa

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say, but you can try one of these:

[how to php encrypt passwords to 128 character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903904/how-to-php-encrypt-passwords-to-128-character)

The beauty of encryption is that you do not decrypt it easily, so it may be hard to find the algorithm.
But actually if you make a password reset in a project, I suppose there should be somehwere also the function for creating the passwords, so you should not guess, but find it in the project.